# Splitting at string and keeping periods

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-split

I'm trying to split a sentence at the .!? while keeping them, but for some reason it's not working correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
$input = "hi i am1. hi i am2.";
$inputX = preg_split("~[.!?]+\K\b~", $input); 

print_r($inputX);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => hi i am1. hi i am2. )
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => hi i am1. [1] => hi i am2. )
```

Comment: Split, splits on the character so don't do a full regex. e.g. `preg_split("~[.!?]~",`. That will remove the puntction though. I'd go `preg_match_all("~(.*?[.!?])\s*~"`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without `\b`, I think it is redundant (if it is not a case) here.

```
$input = "hi i am1. hi i am2.?! hi i am2.?";
$inputX = preg_split("~(?>[.!?]+)\K(?!$)~", $input); 

print_r($inputX);
```

The `(?!$)` is to avoid splitting on matched element, if it is on the end of string, so there will not be an additional empty result. The atomic grouping `?>` is to avoid spliting if there is series of characters on the end of string, like `?!.`(without atomic grouping it would split on `!`, and last result would be single char `.`).  Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hi i am1.
    [1] =>  hi i am2.?!
    [2] =>  hi i am2.?
)
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I need. :)

Comment: Actually, is there a way to make it so it doesn't split at periods that's between numbers? So 3.14 would stay as one string, as oppose to 3 and 14?

Comment: @frosty try with `(?!(?<=\d)[.!?]+\d)(?>([.!?]+))\K(?!$)` is should split on char before or after digit, like `4.` or `.3`, but not between digits, like in `2.3`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you need to do a `preg_split()` but try `preg_match_all()` if that is an option:

```
$input = "hi i am1. hi i am2.";
preg_match_all("/[^\.\?\!]+[\.\!\?]/", $input,$matched);
print_r($matched);
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hi i am1.
            [1] =>  hi i am2.
        )
)
```

Comment: Thought of that, but if 'am2' doesn't have a period, it won't work. I want it to work as long as there's a .!? separating texts.

Comment: `[\.|\!|\?]` doesn't do what you think it does - it includes `|` in the character class. Just use `[.!?]`

Comment: I actually copied that from a different answer to see if it did what the OP was requesting to determine if I should answer or not, and forgot to revert it back to what I originally was going to use (no `|` characters). I still escape characters like `.`, or `?` out of habit...

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what you are expecting

```
$input = "hi i am1. hi i !am?2."; // i have added other ?! symbols also

$inputX = preg_split("/(\.|\!|\?)/", $input,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); 

print_r($inputX)
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => hi i am1 [1] => . [2] => hi i [3] => ! [4] => am [5] => ? [6] => 2 [7] => . [8] => )
```

Comment: i hope this meets your requiremnt

Comment: The `m` modifier isn't doing anything. Also why not use the character class?